# Sending Form Submission response to div

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

After I submit the edit profile form for the FOSUserBundle, I want the response to go to a div. How to do that? I can't do it through jquery as my even handler is not called at all. The response gets loaded as a fresh page.

```
$("#user_management").find('form').submit(function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
       var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
       var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
       console.log('Form clicked.');
       $.ajax(
       {
           url : formURL,
           type: "POST",
           data : postData,
           success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
           {
               //data: return data from server
               loadDataToTarget(data,textStatus,'targetDiv');
           },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
           {
               //if fails      
               console.log('Form submit fail: ' + textStatus);
           }
       });

       //e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
   });
   $("#user_management").find('form').submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Note: The form is in the user_management div. The function works perfectly when I enter the entire code above on the javascript console in a debug mode. But, when I click the submit button, this function is not hit at all and the entire page reloads with the response.

New Information: When I click the submit button, the event is handled by the validator. At this point I wish that the event be available to be captured by ajax, so that the submission can be done through ajax. Instead, after form validation Symfony goes ahead with form submission and reloads the entire page.

Someone please tell me how to let the validator work, but the event be then made available to be grabbed by ajax.

Comment: Please share source? Are you using aJax?

Comment: yes I am using ajax and have updated relevant code. The ajax code that I updated in my question works from the js console but it does not get hit when I click the submit button in the form. I think the event is handled by the FOSUserBundle and it also submits the form. How to get the event tome to my ajax function?

Comment: Does the `$form->isValid()` block evaluate to `true`? If not, I had a similar case some time ago, where the return *inside* the `if` was returning JSON data, but the final return was redirecting. Could be something similar?

Comment: yes, the did the xdebug and found that the $form->isValid() is always false. How to set it to true?

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that I have to add the event listener for the elements for the freshly created ajax elements. Once I did that, ajax took over. I am fine now.. Thanks for providing me with valuable advise.